# AWS IOT policy document

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I have an application where each client has its own thing, for each thing I am creating a certificate and attaching it to the thing, I am also attaching the following policy to the certificate.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
    "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:*********:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

What I want to do is limit a client from accessing other clients' things, and each client can have full access to its thing topic.

The above policy isn't working, clients aren't able to connect at all.
However the following is working (in terms of functionality), but clients are able to publish to all topics.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also the following connects successfully but fails to publish:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:******:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Finally the following connects and publishes successfully.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:******:topic/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

MQTTBox client configs:
[image: client configs]

Publisher:
[image: publisher settings]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy needs an explicit `iot:Connect` statement to allow connections to a `client` resource.

The relevant `client` resource is documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/action-resources.html as

> A client ID ARN - arn:aws:iot:us-east1:123456789012:client/myClientId

For a thing that is registered in the AWS IoT registry, you can use:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:*********:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:*",
      "Resource": ["arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:*********:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"]
    }
  ]
}
```

e.g. This example will allow a thing with client id of `ThingId123` to publish to a topic named `ThingId123`.

See also https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html for an example that appears to closely align to your needs.

Comment: thank you, but that didn't work either. I am using MQTTBox to test, only the action which's Resource is set to (*) is working

Comment: How didn't it work? Is it the client can't connect or can't publish?

From your recent edits I would check that the topic path matches your thing name.

Comment: Using your solution, the client couldn't connect or publish

Comment: So what happens if you replace `${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}` in the policy with the actual thing name?

Comment: doesn't work either.
My thing name is thingy1 so I replaced ${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName} with thingy1, I feel like I am doing something ridiculous  causing this

Comment: Is your thing's client id the same as the thing name?

Comment: I added screenshots from MQTTbox, policy is * for connect and  "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:******:topic/thingy1" for publish, it connects but doesn't publish

Comment: The topic that you need to publish to is just `thingy1`. The 'Topic to publish' entry in MQTTBox should not contain the `arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:******:topic/` part. See some of the examples in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html

Comment: For the connect part of the policy to work (with my example and not using *) then the thing needs to be registered in the AWS IoT registry.

Comment: As an alternative you can use `${iot:ClientId}` in place of `${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}`

Comment: connect works with ${iot:ClientId}, but publish works only with * or thingy1, it is like thing is not registered, but I added it from manage things in IOT core

Comment: @BenT - In the policy page, when I enter action as `iot:Connect`, then what exactly is the purpose of `Resource ARN`? The documentation says `Resource, which specifies the resource or resources on which the action is allowed or denied.`. Here the action is `connect` and in resource we can enter some `clientid`. However, in the real world a device never really connects to any other client id resource (I am assuming client id means another IoT thing). The device either connects to the local greengrass or the IoT core broker. So what exactly does the ClientId in the Resource ARN field signify?

Comment: The ClientId in the resource ARN limits the device to using the given client id(s). From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-policy-actions.html:
`The iot:Connect permission can be used to ensure only authorized clients using a specific client ID can connect.`

Answer (score 0):

after struggling with fine-grained policies myself, 
the accepted answer should be is that that you just forgot the  **/***   at the end of the topic, since AWS uses more nesting to the topic resource,

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Connect"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}",
            ]
        }
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "iot:Publish"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

you can read about is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/pub-sub-policy.html):

also instead of

```
"Resource": [ "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:topic/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
```

you can do

```
 "Resource": [ "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:123456789012:*/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*"
```

this will help you also for subscribing

Comment: The first star in subscription resource property can also be defined as "topicfilter". It's quite a gotcha. I regularly put there just "topic" and nothing works.